# VSTS Release Webapp to more than 30 appservices using Publish Profile

Tags: azure, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, publish-profiles

We have developed a web application using ASP.NET MVC and database in SQL server.

We are having more than 30 clients, each client has their own Azure appservice and Azure SQL database. All the resources are under single subscription.

Now I wanted to deploy the application and database to those 30 clients.

I had setup the CI for the application in VSTS. Now I wanted to setup CD to release the application to all 30 clients.

I do not want to create a separate release environment for each client and do not want to use 30 azure appservice deployment task in single environment. Because the client count will increase in future.

Instead I can add publish profile for each client to the project. In VSTS Release, How can I configure to release to all the publish profiles that are available in the project?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Sage's solution?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I had not yet started to implement, was busy with other tasks. I will let you know once I have done.

Comment: @Saravana Kumar, If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

This article might help you.
[Call MsDeploy from VSTS](https://shazwazza.com/post/deploying-to-azure-from-vsts-using-publish-profiles)

Effectively, you would want to call msdeploy as a task in your release and pass it the deployment profile.